# What if .gitignore ignore itself? Does it affect on "git fetch"?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-fetch

Suppose this scene

1. A git server of some sources codes and some elf binary files
2. This server has no `.gitignore` file.
3. I don't know what new binary file will be added to the git server
4. Every time i build the codes, it will create some new elf binary files.
5. Since there is no `.gitignore` file, after building, i can't `git fetch` or `git pull` because git will promopts `changes not committed`

So i want to solve this, but i can't just make a `.gitignore` with `*.elf` because there are some elf files released with git server.

Of course i can't tell `.gitignore` don't ignore these elf files released with git server because there may be some new elf binary files added to git server in the future

So, what if i create `.gitignore` that ignore itself, so it won't be pushed to git server, but will it affect my `git fetch` process? If there is two differenct `.gitignore` rules in server and in my local computer, which one will `git fetch` obey?

And how can i solve my problem?

Comment: "So, what if i create .gitignore that ignore itself, so it won't be pushed to git server" --- gitignore has nothing to do with pushes. Neither does it something to do with fetch.

Comment: What do you mean? does it mean all things and changes will be pushed onto or fetch from even gitignore choose to ignore them?

Comment: Nope. `.gitignore` only affects what is to be staged and committed. When you perform push/fetch - it does not care about contents. Like it does not care about it at all. What it cares is just a graph.

Comment: So, if i have a gitignore which ignore all *.elf files, and someone else add new elf files on the git server, then i `git fetch`, will this new files be downloaded on my computers?

Comment: Once again: `git fetch` operates with complete solid commit. So what was committed - will be fetched. Unconditionally and completely.

Answer (score 4):

First, stop storing binaries in your repository.  Git is meant to track source code changes, not changes in binaries.

Second, there are actually three locations that are read for ignoring files to be tracked:  `.gitignore` (local project),  `.git/info/exclude` (local project, not public), and a global excludes file, which applies to all Git projects.  Anything in your personal `.git` folder is not shared upstream, so you can feel free to add whatever exclusions you like to that file so that they won't be propagated anywhere else.

It seems like you don't wish to create a `.gitignore` file since you want to avoid the risk with removing the ELF files, but you're welcome to add that exclusion to your local `.git/info/exclude` file.

Comment: This actually doesn't answer my question.First, binary release is really common,such as libraries without source but are required by other sources.Second, this still can't solve "what if git server add some new elf files"

Comment: "First, binary release is really common,such as libraries without source but are required by other sources" --- and for artifacts you use artifactories, not source code control system.